# Minecraft pe doesn't work with internet

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have just updated minecraft 1.11.0 on tab E (Android version 4.4.4). I played a couple of times while signed into xbox live and it was working fine. But when I tried to open minecraft earlier this morning, it crashes at the loading screen. I googled a bit and found out that I can open it without internet and open the internet again when minecraft gets opened. I did close my internet and minecraft worked fine, but the instant i opened my internet again it crashed.

Anyone know what is causing this? And how could it be solved?

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues caused by outdated, locally cached XBox Live credentials. I recommend signing out of XBox Live (or deleting the cached credentials, as outlined [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-20548)).

Comment: This question is about the pocket edition of minecraft for mobile devices. IT has nothing to do with xbox live

Comment: Minecraft Pocket Edition (for iOS and Android) allows you to log in using XBox Live credentials. Upon booting, it logs you in. If your credentials are out-of-date, the game can crash at the loading screen.